# Disable nested key support in angular formly for a single field?

Tags: angular-formly

I've got a model that is returned from an api (that I do not control), that has keys which have dots in it.

```
{
  "permissions": {
     "account.read": true,
     "account.write": false
  }
}
```

When I go to use it in angular formly, it is automatically creating a nested model due to the . in the keys:

```
vm.fields = [
  {
    key: 'permissions',
    fieldGroup: [
     {
       key: 'account.read',
       type: 'input',
       templateOptions: {
         type: 'checkbox',
         label: 'Can view accounts'
       }
    },
    {
       key: 'account.write',
       type: 'input',
       templateOptions: {
         type: 'checkbox',
         label: 'Can create accounts'
       }
    }
];
```

Creates something like this in the model:

```
{
  "permissions": {
     "account": {
       "read": true,
       "write": true
     }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get it to preserve the non-nested keys? The workaround I'm using right now is to replace the . with _ and then transform it back when it's submitted.

Comment: Hmmm... That's a toughy... [This function](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/master/src/run/formlyNgModelAttrsManipulator.js#L46-L50) is the one responsible for that feature. Currently, the only way you can prevent it from running is by [skipping](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/master/src/run/formlyNgModelAttrsManipulator.js#L17-L19) with [`extras.skipNgModelAttrsManipulator`](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/ngmodelattrstemplatemanipulator#disabling)

Comment: Thanks Kent, I'll look into that -- I use the other ngModelAttrsManipulator stuff but maybe I can recreate one without the nested field stuff for this field.